# Invoke a method based on argument with byte buddy

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, byte-buddy, codegen

I have the following interface

```
public interface DatabaseClient {
    void save(Entity entity, Consumer<Long> callback);
    void load(long id, Consumer<Entity> callback);
}
```

and an implementation of this interface called `DatabaseClientImpl`.

I used byte buddy to subclass the interface `DatabaseClient`. The generated class will delegate each method to a class which creates an `Invocation` record.

```
public record Invocation(Method method, Object[] parameters) {}
```

`Invocation` objects will later be passed to an abstract class `ProxyHandler` which implements `java.util.function.Consumer<Invocation>`. What I'm now trying to achieve is to subclass ProxyHandler and call the method stored in `Invocation` with the parameters on an instance of`DatabaseClientImpl`.

This is what I've done so far..

```
public <T> void register(Class<T> intf, T service) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    ProxyHandler proxyHandler = new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(ProxyHandler.class)
        .method(isAbstract())

        // todo intercept and dynamically call method
        //.intercept(MethodCall.invoke(loadMethod)
        //    .on(service)
        //    .with(1L, callback))

        .make()
        .load(ProxyHandler.class.getClassLoader())
        .getLoaded()
        .newInstance();

    proxyHandler.accept(new Invocation(...));
}

public static abstract class ProxyHandler implements Consumer<Invocation> {
}
```

Generally, the approach using MethodCall works but I only added it for testing. Since there are other interfaces than `DatabaseClient` this rather static approach isn't going to work.

So, is there any way to delegate calls to DatabaseClientImpl based on the properties of Invocation?

Comment: That’s a strange detour, to end up calling an interface method on an implementation of that interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem you can better solve with reflection/method handles using a simple `Proxy`, I would assume as you do not need to subclass. You can of course use Byte Buddy, and you can use `MethodCall` and supply additional `MethodCall`s as arguments. In these method calls, you would invoke the corresponding getter on the argument value.